# How to know if Intel chipset can run 64-bit guests on VM?

Tags: virtualbox, chipset

How can I know if my Chipset can run 64-bit guests on my virtual box?

My Chipset model, btw, is Intel 5520

Answer (score 2):

Intel has a site dedicated to telling you information about their CPUs and their chipsets, called [Intel Ark](http://ark.intel.com/). You can choose your product from there, and Intel will tell you every last detail they put into that product.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests):

> VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit
>   host operating systems, provided that the following conditions are
>   met:
>
> 1. You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support.
> 2. You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.
> 3. If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon explicit request.

To tell if your hardware supports hardware virtualization or not, you can use SecurAble (google it).

For further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Hardware_support

Comment: How does this help the user identify if their hardware supports x64?